# Can't access AWS RDS MySQL from Webserver

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, connection

I have an AWS RDS MySQL instance that I'm able to connect to from my personal desktop using MySQL workbench and a PHP page, but once I put the PHP page on my webserver, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 2003 Debugging error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '[SERVERVNAME].ciuo9o7t5ksk.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (111)
```

I've searched and found that typically it is because the incoming IP rules don't allow the port, but I set the security settings to allow all incoming IPs (and I certainly didn't add any special rule for my perosnal PC IP), so not sure what I'm missing.

[image]

I use netfirms for webhosting - they told me that I'll need to configure my AWS instance, but I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

First please check which **security group** is attached with the AWS RDS Mysql Instance, 
[image]

Click on the attached security group and all the rule like this

[image]